# Where can I find Google APIs for Android 3.0?

Tags: android, maps, android-3.0-honeycomb

Where can I find the Google APIs for Android 3.0 (API version 11)? I can't seem to figure out how to add Google Maps to a Honeycomb application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is available!  (I have Google APIS - API Level 11 in Eclipse).
Make sure you are up to date!
So go into the SDK folder, then tools. Launch "android". Make sure you have the last version of "Android SDK Tools" and "Android Platform Tools" under "Android Repository".
If that's OK, you can get the "Android SDK Platform 3.0, revision 1", but what you really want is under "Third Party Add-ons", then under "Google Inc". You should find the latest Google APIS.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean exactly with "the Google APIs", but I suppose you want to start with the [reference](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html). ( http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/index.html , different from the normal android reference)

You can also check the [Hello mapview](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) example.